# how to add xlslib library on 2017 visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2017, xls, xlslib

2008 visual studio uses the xlslib library in the application co-written with QT4. How can I add it to Xlslib library with QT5 and 2017 visual studio.

Comment: There are minimum post lengths for a reason, please don't just say the same thing three times to get round them. What is the exact problem you are having with this library? What have you tried? What error did you encounter? Please show a [mre]

Comment: Most likely you have to obtain binaries compiled with Visual Studio 2015 to 2022. The msvc compiler in VS 2017 is binary incompatible with VS 2008.

Comment: I can't add the xlslib library from 2017 visual studio. It gives a lot of errors in the written code. How can I compile this library? Its page was last updated in 2011 http://xlslib.sourceforge.net/ how can I add this library to my project in visual studio 2017. Can you show how it's done?

Comment: In order to load the 2017 visual studio project written in 2008 visual studio, I need to make this library used in 2008 usable for 2017 visual.

Comment: @drescherjm Most likely you have to obtain binaries compiled with Visual Studio 2015 to 2022. The msvc compiler in VS 2017 is binary incompatible with VS 2008.  
how can i do that. Is it necessary to compile the library in 2015 and 2022?

Comment: No just any version between 2015 and 2022. There is binary compatibility between msvc in Visual Studio 2015 to 2022 but its not compatible otherwise: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-170](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-170)

Comment: ***The Microsoft C++ (MSVC) compiler toolsets in Visual Studio 2013 and earlier don't guarantee binary compatibility across major versions. You can't link object files, static libraries, dynamic libraries, and executables built by different versions of these toolsets. The ABIs, object formats, and runtime libraries are incompatible.***

Comment: ***We've changed this behavior in Visual Studio 2015 and later versions. The runtime libraries and apps compiled by any of these versions of the compiler are binary-compatible. It's reflected in the C++ toolset major number, which starts with 14 for all versions since Visual Studio 2015.***

Comment: @drescherjm how can ı add https://github.com/JanX2/xlslib/tree/rebased-on-svn/xlslib/build/msvc2019,  here I found it for 2019, how can i use this, can these files adapt for 2017 visual stdio or how can i add this to the project.

Comment: I am not sure how that header works with the project.

Comment: @drescherjm  How can that be? is there a way?

Comment: You will probably have to test yourself. You may want to try to upgrade the 2012 project files and put that header in the same folder as the project. I am not sure. I don't have time to spend 30 minutes testing that for you.